# multiple select option with one #id to show n hide table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem about select option. i want to show n hide my table n div with my many select option with the same id, but the result is only effective in first select option. i really need your help so that all my select option work with the same id. Help me guys..!
...

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $('#sts').change(function() {
                $('div.number').hide();
                $('table.number').hide();
                $('#number' + $(this).val()).show();
          }).change();
    });
</script>
```

...

```
  <select name="" id="sts" class="form-select required">


  <option value="">- select -</option>

  <option value="1">Option 1</option>

  <option value="2">Option 2</option>

  <option value="3">Option 3</option>

  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="sts" class="form-select required">

  <option value="">- select -</option>

  <option value="1">Option 1</option>

  <option value="2">Option 2</option>

  <option value="3">Option 3</option>

  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </select>

  <div id="number1" class="number">Option 1</div>

  <div id="number2" class="number">Option 2</div>
  <div id="number3" class="number">Option 3</div>
```

Comment: Same **id** for multiple elements will lead to **id** collision. Try to use name attribute for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('*#sts').change(function() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `id` attribute of a HTML element must be unique. So please change the code to

```
<select name="" id="sts" class="form-select required">


  <option value="">- select -</option>

  <option value="1">Option 1</option>

  <option value="2">Option 2</option>

  <option value="3">Option 3</option>

  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="sts1" class="form-select required">

  <option value="">- select -</option>

  <option value="1">Option 1</option>

  <option value="2">Option 2</option>

  <option value="3">Option 3</option>

  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </select>

  <div id="number1" class="number">Option 1</div>

  <div id="number2" class="number">Option 2</div>
  <div id="number3" class="number">Option 3</div>
```

Now use the code to do the processing by getting the `select` elements through `their class` names:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('select.form-select').change(function() {

                $('div.number').hide();
                $('table.number').hide();
                $('#number' + $(this).val()).show();
          });
</script>
```